# Backspace key delete forward in eclipse

Tags: keyboard, eclipse

As the title says, my <kbd>backspace</kbd> key doesn't delete backward, instead it deletes forward (like when the <kbd>insert</kbd> key is pressed).

I don't know if this is how it should be or if I did something wrong, I'm using windows 7 and it's only happening in my Eclipse Mars, I have checked another text editors, like Word, Notepad, and Netbeans, none of them have this problem.

(<kbd>insert</kbd> is NOT activated).

Comment: This sounds like a keyboard layout problem.  Does the OS keyboard layout match the layout of Eclipse?

Comment: @Ramhound how can I check this?

Comment: I have found the solution in another stackexchance site, I can't mark this as duplicated, so I'll add a link to that question and flag it to move it there...

Comment: This question is on topic here.  You should just answer the question yourself now that you know the solution.  There are of examples of questions existing on multiple sites, that are on topic on each site, which deserve to be answered on each of those sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33866557/3998458).

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys`

In the right side of the window, type "Delete" where it says "type filter text".

Find the `Delete`command where the binding is for 'Backspace', and click on `Unbind Command` button. Click Apply, then OK.

[image: unbingdeletecommand]

Comment: that's perfect.